# Creating Pthreads C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm designing a remake of tetris and need a timer function that runs at the same time as an input function. I'm using pthreads to achieve this, but when I make the call to

`pthread_create(&timer, NULL, Timer(), NULL);`

I receive an error claiming there is no matching function for call to `pthread_create()` despite including `<pthread.h>` in my header.

I noticed that another person asked pretty much the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389384/no-matching-function-call-to-pthread-create). However, I managed to successfully create pthreads on another computer without doing any of what was suggested to that person.

Below is the source code that I am having problems with. I am not asking for you to rewrite it, but rather inform me what's wrong. I'll do the research to fix my code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

void *Timer(void) { //I have tried moving the asterisk to pretty much every
                    //possible position and with multiple asterisks. Nothing works

    time_t time1, time2;

    time1 = time(NULL);

    while (time2 - time1 <= 1) {
        time2 = time(NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {

    pthread_t inputTimer;

    pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, Timer(), NULL); //Error here

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an address of your `Timer` function, not it's return value. Thus

```
pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, &Timer, NULL); // These two are equivalent
pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, Timer, NULL);
```

`pthread_create` expects it's third argument to have the following type: `void *(*)(void*)`; i.e. a function taking a single argument of `void*` and returning `void*`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `pthread_create` the address of the function that you want it to invoke, rather than the return value of the function that you want it to invoke:

```
pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, Timer, NULL);
```

also, your function must have the following signature `void* (void*)`, so it must be changed to:

```
void *Timer(void*) {
    time_t time1, time2;
    time1 = time(NULL);
    while (time2 - time1 <= 1) {
        time2 = time(NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```